# Conditinal Field for Group Fields

Tags: nodes

I have a List Field on a Content Type. Just after that I have a Group Field. I'd like make it visible in relation to the value on the previous List Field.

To sum up, to use Conditional Field Module also for a Group Field.

How is the best wat to do this?

Comment: to clarify, you're able to use Conditional Field module to hide show fields (you've got that figured out), and you just are stuck on a hiding/showing a specific type of field: Group Field. What is a group field?  Like field_group or something else?

Comment: hi! I've solved it using Field Collection. By using this I've been able to create a Group Field inside the Field Collection (I'm using "Field group multiple" to create a multiple fields table) and then Dependencies apply only to Field Collection created. Thanks!